# Hibernate custom type and not well-formed order by clause

Tags: java, hibernate, custom-type

My Class:

```
public class Concurso {
private Long id;
private String nome;
private Date ultimaModificacao;
// getter & setters
}
```

My mapping:

```
    <class name="Concurso" table="xyz">
     <id name="id" unsaved-value="null" type="long"> 
      <column name="ID"/>
     </id>
     <property name="nome"/>
     <property name="ultimaModificacao" type="MyDateTimeType">
      <column name="DT_ALTERACAO" not-null="true" sql-type="DATE"/>
      <column name="HR_ALTERACAO" not-null="true" sql-type="TIME"/>
     </property>
     <query name="find">
     from
     Concurso concurso
     order by
     concurso.ultimaModificacao desc
     </query>
    </class>
```

My custom type 'MyDateTimeType' joins the 2 columns and builds (in the `nullSafeGet` method) a `java.util.Date` object to be configured in the 'Concurso' instances.

When I load the named query 'find' and execute the `query.list()`, the generated sql query is something like:

```
select 
c.ID, c.DT_ALTERACAO, c.HR_ALTERACAO
from
xyz c
order by c.DT_ALTERACAO, c.HR_ALTERACAO desc
```

The problem is in the 'order' clause. Only the second column receives the 'desc' word. The correct should be:

```
select 
c.ID, c.DT_ALTERACAO, c.HR_ALTERACAO
from
xyz c
order by c.DT_ALTERACAO DESC, c.HR_ALTERACAO DESC
```

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use criteria for this

```
List concursosList = sess.createCriteria(Concurso.class)
.add( Restrictions.like("nome", "F%")
.addOrder( Order.desc("DT_ALTERACAO") )
.addOrder( Order.desc("HR_ALTERACAO") )
.setMaxResults(50)
.list();
```

This criteria will add as many filters you want for columns. I hope this helps.

Comment: I could do this with Criteria or SQL native query, but I want to do with pure HQL :)

Comment: @Marcos Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: I created a field named, for example `my_timestamp` with the formula `timestamp(dt_alteracao,hr_alteracao)`. Then, I did the ordering by this field. It is a very ugly solution, but it works